# How to get the filepath from a frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

To get the filename from a frame I can do:

```
exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
current_frame = exc_traceback.tb_frame
filename = current_frame.f_code.co_filename
# example.py
# how to get '/Users/david/Desktop/Log/example.py' ?
```

However, I don't see a way to get the path of the file. How would one get the complete `filepath` from the stack? (Actually, the only way I currently see how to get it is using a regex from `traceback.format_exc()`, but that seems pretty crude.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) should solve this for you:

```
filepath = os.path.abspath(current_frame.f_code.co_filename)
```